# Putting source information into LLVM bitcode files for debugging compiler errors

Tags: compiler-construction, f#, code-generation, llvm, llvm-fs

I'm making a basic compiler and want to put the source lines of code somewhere near the llvm code that is produced for easy debugging. For example:

```
proc f(a:Int, b:Int):Int {
    return a + b;
}

start {
    print f(1,2);
    return 0;
}
```

Should be annotated somehow with the source like so:

```
@numFmt = internal constant [4 x i8] c"%d\0A\00"

declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...) nounwind

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %print.0 = call i32 @f(i32 1, i32 2)     ; print f(1,2) maybe using a comment
  %tmp.3 = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8]* @numFmt, i32 0, i32 0), i32 %print.0)
"return 0    - or perhaps using a basic block":
  ret i32 0
}

define i32 @f(i32 %a, i32 %b) {
entry:
  "return a + b" = <or the result of some dummy operation that doesn't get stripped away"
  %return.0 = add i32 %a, %b
  ret i32 %return.0
}
```

Any solutions/ways of doing this? (I'm using the llvm-fs bindings btw, but I just want a way that will work with the IR)

Comment: +1 for asking a question about LLVM and F#. :-)

Comment: Why do you want to tie an actual source code in? Use llvm metadata to store the location triplets (file, line, column) for each instruction.

Comment: @SK-logic: It's just for simpler debugging of the compiler itself - you can see what part of IR links to which part of source without having to go through a file/line/col lookup. Take a look at http://pastebin.com/46h4fTCg (code from a random stack machine I've targeted before) to see what I've been doing before.

Comment: I see. You can always use a text metadata like this, or, alternatively (and it is better for debugging too) you can implement a preprocessor which will read both IR and your source and display the corresponding lines of code in between instructions with metadata.

Comment: Yes, metadata nodes seem to be the way forward here. Alas, I am using the llvm-fs bindings which uses the LLVM C api and looks like i'll need to ask another question about how to actually make metadata nodes.

Comment: See my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034586/how-to-add-metadata-nodes-using-the-llvm-c-api-llvm-fs-bindings

Comment: @CallumRogers, why do you want to use a named metadata? Use simple metadata nodes (linked to values). llvm-c API provides everything you'll need.

Comment: To be truly honest, I have no real idea about how to do anything with metadata, I would be happy if I could just produce some metadata, any metadata, anything so I could could work from there.